# How to disable form validation for some submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

In my jsp form page, I have two submit button "Save" and "Cancel". When I click on both buttons it validates the form. I tried to put keyword "formnovalidate" for cancel button. But its not working.

Here I mentioned my button code:

```
<form id = "myForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
..........
<tr >
<td class="td_left"><input type="submit" value="save" onclick="form.action='${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/insert'"/></td>
<td class="td_right"><input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="form.action='${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/home'" formnovalidate  /></td>
</tr>
................
</form>
```

Validations:

```
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["spcrId"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("SPCR ID must be filled out");
    return false;
}
}
```

What is the way to disable form validations for "Cancel" button?

Comment: One form shouldn't have two submit buttons. You would need to have a conditional statement setup in your javascript to validate based on what element is clicked. However, in reality, your cancel button should just be refactored to be a simple link that directs you to the `/home`/ URL.

Comment: What validations are you using??

Comment: @Manwal updated question.

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem was because you, on the form's `onsubmit` attribute, placed a validation call. So, something like this should work without that `onsubmit` attribute:

```html
<button name="action" class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Previous" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">Previous</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of type = "submit" you have to use

```
 <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
```

or you can use

```
<button type="cancel" onclick="window.location='http://your.com';return
false;">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: `<input type="reset" value="Cancel" />` would be better choice.

Comment: yes if there is a form with two buttons one is submit then second one has to be reset. I don't get it what is the use of cancel if just for navigation to home page then type='reset' and type='button' both can be used. i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="this.form.setAttribute('novalidate', 'novalidate'); form.action='${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/home'"  />
```

By setting the form's `novalidate` attribute on the click event you can bypass the validation for only that button.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var myFormVar = document.myForm.FieldName.value;
if ((myFormVar == "") ) {
   document.myForm.FieldName.value = ''; 
   document.myForm.FieldName.focus();
   alert ("alert here");
   return;
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:-

```
  `<button type="button"></button>`
```

Comment: What useless nonsense is this?